# Android Methods: Method 1 returns empty String value with error and Method 2 returns a null pointer exceptions

Tags: java, android

Can someone help me to see what is wrong with these two functions
**Method 1 returns empty String value without any error and Method 2 returns a null pointer exceptions**
I have tried all the similar examples I could find here but still have issues for days. Thanks in advance.

```
//Funtion1 Converting File to Base64.encode String type but returns empty string
        public String getStringFile(File f) {
             InputStream inputStream = null; 
                String encodedFile= "", lastVal;
                try {
                    String uriString = filePath2.toString();
                    f = new File(uriString).getAbsoluteFile();
                    inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];//specify the size to allow
                int bytesRead;
                ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                Base64OutputStream output64 = new Base64OutputStream(output, Base64.DEFAULT);

                    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        output64.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                output64.close();
                encodedFile =  output64.toString();
                } 
                 catch (FileNotFoundException e1 ) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                Log.i("Base64 String", "=" +  encodedFile);
                Log.v("Base64 String", "=" +  encodedFile);
                Log.e("Base64 String", "=" +  encodedFile);
                lastVal = encodedFile;
                return lastVal;

        }

// Funtion 2 also Converting File to Base64 encode String but returns NullPointerException
    public String getStringFile(File f) throws FileNotFoundEception, IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = null; 
        String encodedFile= "", lastVal;
         f = new File(f.getAbsoluthPath());
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];//specify the size to allow
        int bytesRead;
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Base64OutputStream output64 = new Base64OutputStream(output, Base64.DEFAULT);

            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                output64.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        output64.close();
        encodedFile =  output.toString();



         return = encodedFile;

    }
```

**This is the complete code below.** Every other thing is working except for this task. Thanks

```
package com.aquacareer;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.OpenableColumns;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Base64OutputStream;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class Employee_Reg extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener, OnClickListener {
    byte[] bytes;
    RelativeLayout rl;
    String strCat1, strCat2, imagePath, docPath, result, displayName, encodedFile;
    Spinner spCat1, spCat2;
    Button b1, b2, b3;
    EditText ed1, ed2, ed3, ed4, ed5, ed6, ed7, ed8, ed9, ed10, ed11;
    String fullname, password, comfPassword, gender, email, contAddr, phoneNo, mobileNo, currLoc, currSal, currInd,
            quali, carProfile, path, path2;

    Intent intent;
    TextView txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4, txt5, txt6, txt7;
    int counter = 3;
    Uri filePath, filePath2;

    String URL = "http://www.aquabytestechnologies.com/aquacareer/android/employeeregister.php";
    // Alert Dialog Manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    public static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
    public static final String KEY_FILE = "file";

    // Image request code
    private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 2;
    private int PICK_FILE_REQUEST = 1;

    // storage permission code
    private static final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 123;

     InputStream inputStream = null ; 
     ByteArrayOutputStream output = null;
     Base64OutputStream output64 = null;


    // Uri to store the image uri
    // private Uri filePath;
    private File fileDoc;
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_employee_reg);

        // getActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF' >
        // AquaCareer </font>"));
        getActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF' ><h1>AquaCareer</h1></font>"));
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1c2833")));

        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        ed3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt3);
        ed4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt4);
        ed5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt5);
        ed6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt6);
        ed7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt7);
        ed8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt8);
        ed9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt9);
        ed10 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt10);
        ed11 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt11);

        txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        txt3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        txt4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        txt5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        txt6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        txt7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        txt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txt3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txt5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txt7.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        spCat1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spCat2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        List<String> listGender = new ArrayList<String>();
        listGender.add("Select Gender");
        listGender.add("Male");
        listGender.add("Female");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Employee_Reg.this, R.layout.spinner_item,
                listGender);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item2);
        spCat1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        List<String> listQual = new ArrayList<String>();
        listQual.add("Select Highest Qualification");
        listQual.add("PHD");
        listQual.add("Masters");
        listQual.add("First Degree");
        listQual.add("HND");
        listQual.add("OND");
        listQual.add("Diploma");
        listQual.add("Secondary Cert");
        listQual.add("Primary Cert");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Employee_Reg.this, R.layout.spinner_item,
                listQual);
        dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item2);
        spCat2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);

        spCat1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spCat2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        this.b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.b3.setOnClickListener(this);

        ed3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String strPass1 = ed2.getText().toString();
                String strPass2 = ed3.getText().toString();
                if (strPass1.equals(strPass2)) {
                    txt2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    txt2.setText("Passwords Match");

                } else {
                    txt2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    txt2.setText("Passwords don't Match");
                }
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
            showFileChooser();
        }

        else if (v.getId() == R.id.button2) {
            fullname = ed1.getText().toString().trim();
            password = ed2.getText().toString().trim();
            comfPassword = ed3.getText().toString().trim();
            gender = spCat1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
            email = ed4.getText().toString().trim();
            contAddr = ed5.getText().toString().trim();
            phoneNo = ed6.getText().toString().trim();
            mobileNo = ed7.getText().toString().trim();
            currLoc = ed8.getText().toString().trim();
            currSal = ed9.getText().toString().trim();
            currInd = ed10.getText().toString().trim();
            quali = spCat2.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
            carProfile = ed11.getText().toString().trim();
            path = txt5.getText().toString().trim();
            path2 = txt7.getText().toString().trim();
            // Check if username, password is filled
            if (fullname.trim().length() > 0 && password.trim().length() > 0 && comfPassword.trim().length() > 0
                    && gender.trim().length() > 0 && email.trim().length() > 0 && contAddr.trim().length() > 0
                    && phoneNo.trim().length() > 0 && mobileNo.trim().length() > 0 && currLoc.trim().length() > 0
                    && currSal.trim().length() > 0 && currInd.trim().length() > 0 && carProfile.trim().length() > 0
                    && path.trim().length() > 0) {
                // For testing puspose username, password is checked with sample
                // data3E 54
                String strPass1 = ed2.getText().toString();
                String strPass2 = ed3.getText().toString();
                if (strPass1.equals(strPass2)) {
                    if (gender.equals("Male") || gender.equals("Female")) {

                        if (quali.equals("Select Highest Qualification")) {
                            alert.showAlertDialog(Employee_Reg.this, "Registration Failed..", "Select Qualification",
                                    false);
                        } else {

                            registerUser();

                        }
                    } else {
                        alert.showAlertDialog(Employee_Reg.this, "Registration Failed..", "Select Genger", false);
                    }

                } else {
                    alert.showAlertDialog(Employee_Reg.this, "Registration Failed..", "Passwords don't Match", false);
                }

            } else {
                // user didn't entered username or password
                // Show alert asking him to enter the details
                alert.showAlertDialog(Employee_Reg.this, "Registration Failed..", "Please fill all details", false);
            }

        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.button3) {
            showFileChooser2();
        }

    }

    private void registerUser() {
        register();
    }

    // method to show file chooser for image
        private void showFileChooser() {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            try {
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(Employee_Reg.this, "Please install a File Manager.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    // method to show file chooser for resume
        private void showFileChooser2() {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("*/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            try {
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Document"), PICK_FILE_REQUEST);
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(Employee_Reg.this, "Please install a File Manager.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        // handling the image chooser activity result
        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                filePath = data.getData();
                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                    // imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

                    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE },
                                STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
                    } else {

                        imagePath = getPath(filePath);
                        txt5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        txt5.setText(imagePath);
                        Log.i("Base64 imagePath", "=" + imagePath);

                        alert.showAlertDialog(Employee_Reg.this, "Image Loaded..", "Photo Successfully Selected", true);
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (requestCode == PICK_FILE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                filePath2 = data.getData();
                try {
                    // docPath = getPath2(filePath2);
                    String uriString = filePath2.toString();
                    fileDoc = new File(uriString);

                    docPath = fileDoc.getAbsolutePath();

                    if (uriString.startsWith("content://")) {
                        Cursor cursor = null;
                        try {
                            cursor = Employee_Reg.this.getContentResolver().query(filePath2, null, null, null, null);
                            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                            }
                        } finally {
                            cursor.close();
                        }
                    } else if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {
                        displayName = fileDoc.getName();
                    }

                    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

                    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE },
                                STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
                    } else {

                        txt7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        txt7.setText(displayName);
                        //Log.i("Base64 URIString", "=" + uriString);
                        //Log.i("Base64 docPath", "=" + docPath);
                        alert.showAlertDialog(Employee_Reg.this, "Resume Loaded..", "Resume Successfully Selected", true);
                    }

                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

        // Converting Bitmap image to Base64.encode String type
        public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
            String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
            return encodedImage;
        }

        // Converting File to Base64.encode String type
        public String getStringFile(File f) {
             InputStream inputStream = null; 
                String encodedFile= "", lastVal;
                try {
                    String uriString = filePath2.toString();
                    f = new File(uriString).getAbsoluteFile();
                    inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];//specify the size to allow
                int bytesRead;
                ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                Base64OutputStream output64 = new Base64OutputStream(output, Base64.DEFAULT);

                    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        output64.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                output64.close();
                encodedFile =  output64.toString();
                } 
                 catch (FileNotFoundException e1 ) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                Log.i("Base64 String", "=" +  encodedFile);
                Log.v("Base64 String", "=" +  encodedFile);
                Log.e("Base64 String", "=" +  encodedFile);
                lastVal = encodedFile;
                return lastVal;

        }




        // method to get the file Name from uri
        public String getPath(Uri uri) {

            String uriString = uri.toString();
            File myFile = new File(uriString);

            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            String mPath = myFile.getAbsolutePath();
            String dispName = null;

            if (uriString.startsWith("content://")) {
                Cursor cursor = null;
                try {
                    cursor = Employee_Reg.this.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        dispName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    }
                } finally {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            } else if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {
                dispName = myFile.getName();
            }

            return dispName;
        }

        // Requesting permission
        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        private void requestStoragePermission() {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                return;

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                // If the user has denied the permission previously your code will
                // come to this block
                // Here you can explain why you need this permission
                // Explain here why you need this permission

            }
            // And finally ask for the permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE },
                    STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
        }

        // This method will be called when the user will tap on allow or deny
        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

            // Checking the request code of our request
            if (requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {

                // If permission is granted
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Displaying a toast
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted now you can read the storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    // Displaying another toast if permission is not granted
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Oops you just denied the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.signup, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.abt) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "We are in About US", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }
            if (id == R.id.conUs) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "We are in Contact Us", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    private void register()  {

        class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>  {
            ProgressDialog loading;
            final String fullname = ed1.getText().toString().trim();
            final String password = ed2.getText().toString().trim();
            // final String comfPassword = ed3.getText().toString().trim();
            final String gender = spCat1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
            final String email = ed4.getText().toString().trim();
            final String contAddr = ed5.getText().toString().trim();
            final String phoneNo = ed6.getText().toString().trim();
            final String mobileNo = ed7.getText().toString().trim();
            final String currLoc = ed8.getText().toString().trim();
            final String currSal = ed9.getText().toString().trim();
            final String currInd = ed10.getText().toString().trim();
            final String quali = spCat2.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
            final String carProfile = ed11.getText().toString().trim();
            final String path = txt5.getText().toString().trim();
            final String path2 = txt7.getText().toString().trim();
            final String image = getStringImage(bitmap);
            final String file = getStringFile(fileDoc);
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();





            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(Employee_Reg.this, "Please Wait: ", "Performing Registration", true,
                        true);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params){


                HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();
                param.put("fullname", fullname);
                param.put("email", email);
                param.put("password", password);
                param.put("gender", gender);
                param.put("contAddr", contAddr);
                param.put("phoneNo", phoneNo);
                param.put("mobileNo", mobileNo);
                param.put("currLoc", currLoc);
                param.put("currSal", currSal);
                param.put("currInd", currInd);
                param.put("quali", quali);
                param.put("carProfile", carProfile);
                param.put("path", path);
                param.put("path2", path2);
                param.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
                param.put(KEY_FILE, file);

                String result = rh.sendPostRequest(URL, param);

                return result;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("Sorry, email id already exists")) {

                    alert.showAlertDialog(Employee_Reg.this, "Registration Failed..",
                            "Sorry, email id already exists, choose another email.", false);
                } else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                    alert.showAlertDialog(Employee_Reg.this, "Successful Registration..",
                            "We have just sent you an email for confirmation before you log-in.", true);
                    ed1.setText("");
                    ed2.setText("");
                    ed3.setText("");
                    ed4.setText("");
                    ed5.setText("");
                    ed6.setText("");
                    ed7.setText("");
                    ed8.setText("");
                    ed9.setText("");
                    ed10.setText("");
                    ed11.setText("");
                    txt5.setText("");
                    txt7.setText("");
                    txt3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    txt3.setText("We have just sent you an email for confirmation before you log-in.");

                } else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("test")) {
                    // username / password doesn't match
                    alert.showAlertDialog(Employee_Reg.this, "Registration Failed..",
                            "You cannot register empty details", false);

                } else {
                    // if no category not is selected
                    alert.showAlertDialog(Employee_Reg.this, "Registration Failed..", s, false);

                }
            }

        }

        RegisterUser ru = new RegisterUser();
        ru.execute();
        }

}
```

Comment: Run with the debugger and use a breakpoint to stop and step through the code.

Comment: There are a number of errors in this code which mean it simply won't compile. Please post your actual code.

Comment: It would have been great if you state what are you trying to achieve!

Comment: @Karakuri I have done that sir and I have been logging the return values and the arguments to see what the functions are both returning, I realized that the second function returning a Null Pointer seems to be the correct one because it returns a value but doesn't see the file object and the other one without an error sees the file object when called. I will appreciate your assistance. I have spent 3 complete days on this problem. I@Emmanuel Mtali  I have posted the the full code.  Regards

Comment: @AndyTurner  I will like to know what are the errors sir and best options to solve them. Though the code is working without any compilation or run-time error except for the method returning empty string which makes the uploaded document to also be empty

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the particular function that was returning a null value was the right function then I decided to know why it was returning null value.

I decided to declare the following object and value type variables globally and then initialized them in the onCreate() method.

```
    InputStream inputStream = null ; 
     ByteArrayOutputStream output = null;
     Base64OutputStream output64 = null;
     byte[] buffer;
     int bytesRead;
     String encodedFile;

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       buffer = new byte[10240];//specify the size to allow

         output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         output64 = new Base64OutputStream(output, Base64.DEFAULT);


        encodedFile =  output64.toString();
}



public String getStringFile(File f) {
             InputStream inputStream = null; 

                try {
                    //Please remember that filePath2 is an object of Uri 
                    String uriString = filePath2.toString();
                    f = new File(uriString).getAbsoluteFile();
                    inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);



                    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        output64.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                output64.close();
                encodedFile =  output64.toString();
                } 
                 catch (FileNotFoundException e1 ) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                return encodedFile;

        }
```

Finally, Let's take note that variables (i.e. value or object type variables) declared globally that are expected to be accessed severally within the activity class should be initialized in the onCreate Method for them to return their values at any point of the class that it will be called except otherwise we want to re-initialize them for a different values.